# Another way to reference $this in PHP?

Tags: php, this

Is there any other **way** to reference the **current object** in **php** other than the usual `$this` ???

Thank you

p.s.: I was thinking of perhaps a *hidden* or *shorthand* form..

Comment: `$this` seems pretty shorthand to me.

Comment: Because I've seen some code where sometimes the `->`was used on its own, and I thought that might be another way of saying `$this->`

Comment: Why don't you ask if `->` can be used on it's own, and if so, what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
$t = $this
```

Comment: I can't say it isn't true. But I was thinking more in the lines of a core-php feature...

Answer (score 4):

No : that's precisely what the special-pseudo-variable `$this` is for.